# generic programming in controller for interface between model and view

Tags: c++, boost, model-view-controller, generic-programming

I am creating a MVC framework for my project in C++. Below is controller source/pseudo code snippet. As you can see, that I have to put explicit check for each type. I have stored type for each property of object(model). Is there a way to avoid this switch case?

```
for each property P of object:
    switch(type of P)
    {
        case(type_int):
         {
             int value;
             model->fetch(value, P->id);
             writer->write(value, P->id);
             break;
         }
        case(type_float):
         {
             float value;
             model->fetch(value, P->id);
             writer->write(value, P->id);
             break;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this template function in place of switch

```
  template<typename T>
  void func()
  {
     T value;
     model->fetch(value, P->id);
     writer->write(value, P->id);
 }
```

Comment: But I would still need switch statement.

Comment: @shampa you dont need a switch statement.
Call function as follows func<type>()

Comment: I still need to associate property corresponding to its type. I can't associate basic type int,char* etc. to property.

Comment: @shampa if your property is a user defined type even now it will work this way. Template can handle POD(like int, char) and type you defined like property(if it is) in same way.  As you keep properties in a container in your example  it should be a user defined type

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct pred{

      void operator()(T x)
      {
        //implemnt algorithm
     }
      T value;
};

class property{

};

int main()
{
   std::vector<property> myShape;

   std::for_each(myShape.begin(),myShape.end(), pred<property>());
   std::cout<<"Done"<<std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does `value` *actually* come from, because you can use that to drive the generics. As given, there's no way to prevent the switch, because the switch *also* decides the type of the value. If replace the switch with a variant (assuming you didn't want runtime polymorphism) you can make this work.

The astute reader will note that of course, somewhere internally, a type switch still happens. The essential differences are that

- variants can be compile-time optimized away<sup>[1]</sup>, in which case the type switch need not be present in the generated code or is faster
- the type switch is hidden, the programmer thinks on a higher abstraction level

That said, if it brings complexity, consider simpler options. This might be premature optimization

---

<sup>[1]</sup> in far more (complicated) cases than *de-virtualization* usually happens